# bash function/alias for multi-archive unrar

Tags: bash, function, alias, unrar

I'm trying to write a simple bash alias/function (whichever I get working the quickest), that unrars multi-rar archives. None of my attempts work though.

The plain command invoked in the shell doesn't work either, which I guess is probably the gist of the problem:

```
find . \( -name *.rar -and -not -name *.part*.rar \) -or -name *.part01.rar -exec unrar x {} \;
```

The find part of the command seems to do its work fine, although the -exec doesn't seem to be invoked at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the unrar work individually (I haven't used unrar)? Try using xargs..

```
find . \( -name *.rar -and -not -name *.part*.rar \) -or -name *.part01.rar | xargs -I {} unrar x {}
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Think it's peculiar that I can't get it to work with -exec though. I actually tried the same thing but without the -I and {}, so nothing worked :) Thanks!